# Is it possible to get current time plus 3 seconds in setInterval in JavaScript (Jquery)?

Tags: javascript

I wonder to seek that to get function with delay of current time plus 3 seconds in setInterval (or alternative approach but in javascript).

my code is here

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "chat_online.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#online').html(data);
        }
    });
}, 3000); /* here I want current time plus 3 seconds*/
```

Comment: what isnt working with your code?

Comment: by current time, do you mean the second value of current time ? i.e if the time is 23:19:`07` you want `07s+3s = 10s` ?

Comment: Your code already establishes the interval timer such that the first time the callback is invoked will be 3 seconds after the call to `setInterval()`.

Comment: If you only want the call to happen *once* then use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`.

Comment: The `3000` already represents 3 seconds after the current time. We need some more clarification on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Prasanna you idea seems goes to solution..

Comment: @CodeDraken kindly see the idea in above of comment of Prasanna Actually I want multi users throw function with the same time which should be based on common actual global time..

Answer (score 0):

in the first, you must think that your code doing what ?
i mean you call an async function in a timer , async function may have delay or wait for server ... then every 3 second you send a request without receive success from last one !
so i offer this code except yours :

```
var online = $('#online');
function getOnline (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "chat_online.php",
        method: "POST",

    }).then(()=>{
        online.html(data);
        setTimeout(getOnline,3000);
    });
};

getOnline();
```

top code first send a request and after receive response from server

> (in this code just success is process. you must actually have a plan
>   for fail request)

, three second after run it again . i know it is not exactly what you want but must consider async functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the second value of the current time by

```
var sec = new Date().getUTCSeconds();
var timeOutVariable = sec + 3; // add 3 sec to it

setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
        url: "chat_online.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#online').html(data);
        }
    });
}, timeOutVariable * 1000); // our variable here
```

Not that the thing with `setInterval` is that once you `setInterval` you can not change the time of `setInterval`. In that case you will have to recursively `setTimeout` to get the desired effect.

```
function timeOut(time) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      /* your stuffs here */
      // recalculate sec val and settimeout again
      recursiveTimeoutFunc();
    },
    time
  )
}
// calculate seconds in here
function recursiveTimeoutFunc() {
  var sec = new Date().getUTCSeconds();
  var timeOutVariable = sec + 3; // add 3 sec to it
  timeOut(timeOutVariable * 1000); // call from here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You asked for an alternative approach.  Your current setup will run the Ajax code every three seconds.  To run the code strictly once after an interval of time:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("this code runs after 3 seconds");}, 3000);
```

Comment: "or alternative approach"